# Find edge between two boxes

Tags: geometry

I am building prototype tool to draw simple diagrams.

I need to draw an arrow between two boxes, the problem is I have to find edges of two boxes so that the arrow line does not intersect with the box.

This is the drawing that visualize my problem

[image]

Given size and position of both boxes. How to find $x_1,y_1$ and $x_2,y_2$ ?

Comment: I think a line clipping algorithm might work, take a look at [Cohen Sutherlan Clipping](http://www.academictutorials.com/graphics/graphics-cohen-sutherland-clipping.asp)

Comment: Please specify the known points on each box. The answer should be simple once the points are known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First a technical solution : draw the line first (your first draw) and then the boxes as 'filled rectangles' then no more line 'inside' should be visible (works best using double-buffering).

Now a mathematical solution supposing that the line joins the centers $(c_1,d_1)$ and $(c_2,d_2)$ of your boxes.

Let's set $\Delta_x:=c_2-c_1$ and $\Delta_y:=d_2-d_1$
We'll work out the problem for box 1 of half-width $w=\frac{W_1}2$ and half-height $h=\frac{H_1}2$ and consider the center as the origin of coordinates (for box 2 you'll just have to change the signs of $\Delta_x$ and  $\Delta_y$ and consider $W_2$ and $H_2$ instead, if the two boxes have the same ratio $\frac hw$ you may write both solutions in parallel!).

If $w\cdot
|\Delta_y|\gt h\cdot|\Delta_x|\ \ $ (that is if $\left|\frac{\Delta_y}{\Delta_x}\right|\gt \frac hw$ : the intersection is at top or bottom)

- If $\Delta_y\gt 0$ then the solution is $(h\frac{\Delta_x}{\Delta_y},h)$
- Else the solution is $(-h\frac{\Delta_x}{\Delta_y},-h)$

Else   (if $\left|\frac{\Delta_y}{\Delta_x}\right|\le \frac hw$ : the intersection is at left or right)

- If $\Delta_x\gt 0$ then the solution is $(w,w\frac{\Delta_y}{\Delta_x})$
- Else the solution is $(-w,-w\frac{\Delta_y}{\Delta_x})$

Note that these solutions $(s_x,x_y)$ all verify $\frac{s_y}{s_x}= \frac{\Delta_y}{\Delta_x}$ as they should. To find the actual solution you'll just have to add the position of the center of the object to get $(c_1+s_x,\  d_1+s_y)$. If you need a little space over the boxes just increase a bit $w$ and $h$.

Hoping this helped,

---

UPDATE2 for two parallel lines distant of $2\epsilon$.

Set $o_x:=\epsilon\sqrt{1+(\frac{\Delta_x}{\Delta_y})^2}$ the horizontal offset (or $0$ if $\Delta_y=0$)
Set $o_y:=\epsilon\sqrt{1+(\frac{\Delta_y}{\Delta_x})^2}$ the vertical offset (or $0$ if $\Delta_x=0$)
$\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ is the [sign function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)

If $\Delta_y\neq 0$ and $|(o_x+h\frac{\Delta_x}{\Delta_y}|\le w$

- a solution is : $\textrm{sgn}(\Delta_y)\cdot (o_x+h\frac{\Delta_x}{\Delta_y},h)$

Else (verify that $|(-o_y+w\frac{\Delta_y}{\Delta_x}|\le h$)

- a solution is : $\textrm{sgn}(\Delta_x)\cdot (w,-o_y+w\frac{\Delta_y}{\Delta_x})$

If $\Delta_y\neq 0$ and $|(-o_x+h\frac{\Delta_x}{\Delta_y}|\le w$

- a solution is : $\textrm{sgn}(\Delta_y)\cdot (-o_x+h\frac{\Delta_x}{\Delta_y},h)$

Else  (verify that $|(o_y+w\frac{\Delta_y}{\Delta_x}|\le h$)

- a solution is : $\textrm{sgn}(\Delta_x)\cdot (w,o_y+w\frac{\Delta_y}{\Delta_x})$

These solutions $(s_x,s_y)$ are relative to the center of the box $(c_i,d_i)$. The actual solutions should be $(c_i+s_x,d_i+s_y)$. As previously the sign of $\Delta_x$ and $\Delta_y$ must be changed for the second box.

You'll have to reverify all this (I changed the $o_y$ in $-o_y$ in both 'else').

Comment: perfect, this is what i am looking for. Thanks raymond.

Comment: It works for single line, Now I wanted to add double line between those two box, It's always wrong... I'm pulling my hair because of this --"

Comment: Wow, thanks for the update. After implementing that, my line is always in the top right corner of the screen (0,0) to (x,y). Am I missing something?

Comment: When I Add second solution (ex,ey) to first solution (c1+sx, d1+sy), so it become (c1+sx+ex,d1+sy+ey) the first line is crossing with second line in the middle.

Comment: @Rizky: of course the solutions $(s_x,s_y)\ $ provided were relative to the center of the box and you had to convert this in $(c_i+s_x,d_i+s_y)\ $. Anyway I'll reverify my solutions...

Comment: It works!. Thank you very much. You save my day raymond :D